# how to define and assign value for a python dictionary with dynamic name？

Tags: python

I have a set of string variables in Python code. I want to create a set of dictionaries with names as strings. And I also want to assign values for these dictionary using variable values.

I am wondering how to write code for this?

Please note that, in below code, at line `my_func1_dict = xxx`, I also need to fill the `func1` with a variable value.

For example:

```
name = {func1, func2, fun3}
exec("my_%s_dict = %s" % (name[0], {}))
my_func1_dict = xxx
```

Comment: Common rookie question. Use a dict of dicts.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. It seems that if you want variable names for your dictionaries, you should put them inside a containing dictionary rather than do this. Consider that you'll have to continue to use `exec` to access these dictionaries programmatically in the future.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The duplicate link you have given does not address the question of aaltonen, please provide a better link

Answer (score 0):

```
name = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3']
exec("my_%s_dict = %s" % (name[0], {}))
my_func1_dict['somekey'] = 'xxx'
print(my_func1_dict)
#{'somekey': 'xxx'}
```

Fixed your code for you
You can also use a dict of dicts like what Mad_Physicist suggested, but that would require more code